# What meta learners are used by h2o.automl() to build the ensembles?

Tags: h2o, automl

I am wondering what meta learners are used by h2o.automl() to build the ensembles. So far all the ensembles I've seen were GLMs. Is it because h2o.automl() uses only glm as the meta learner or due to the limited number of base models (25 -50 with my setting), glm is always the best choice?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

H2OAutoML uses GLM as a default metalearner algo, and we're not currently trying multiple metalearners to find the best one (this may change in future releases).

For now, you can train a different ensemble using the autoML models as base models:

```py
aml = H2OAutoML(project_name="my_aml",
                ...,
                keep_cross_validation_predictions=True) # important if you want to stack the models later

aml.train(...)

# train another ensemble using GBM as algo metalearner
lb = aml.leaderboard
base_models = [m for m in [lb[i,0] for i in range(lb.nrows)] 
                 if 'StackedEnsemble' not in m]

se = h2o.estimators.H2OStackedEnsembleEstimator(
    base_models=base_models,
    metalearner_algorithm='gbm',
    ...
)
```